# I want to be able to access to documents through a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to be able to access to documents through a MySQL database(for example I want to create a table that has users and each user has some documents that they stored in alfresco so I want to access to them through this table)

Answer (score 0):

Application layer of Alfresco managed whole database itself. You should not change this database directly. If you want to deal with permission to files, use standard feature https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/using/permissions).

Comment: 1. What is you question  
2. What have you done so far, and what specific problem have you encountered that you are seeking help with
3. You cross posted the more or less same thing again and again:  
    - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72727470/1898538  
    - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72784842/1898538