# access to documents in alfresco repository through a table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, api, rest, alfresco

so my goal is to be able to access to files that I uploaded to `alfresco repository` through `MySQL` database, I create a table of `clients(id ,name ,document)` and each client had a document (pdf) that stored in `alfresco repository` that will be accessible through this table.
I did some research and I found out that I could get files by `rest-API` but don't find how to store it in `MySQL` database
I want to use the Alfresco APIs to get documents from the repository and to store them into the MySQL Database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why would you want to store large binary files in a mysql database? In general it's a pretty terrible idea... Why not just leave the files in Alfresco, and query Alfresco when you want to get them back?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you want to access a document in Alfresco from a custom MySQL db? This sounds to me like a very crude pattern and should be solved by an application outside the DB which accesses your custom db and Alfresco via REST API.